# Build simple multiArch dockerfile without emulation

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

If I have a simple dockerfile with only COPY commands and no RUN commands, How can I build it and push it to a repo without running any emulation?

I am trying to build on bitbucket which [has these restrictions](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines/#Docker-BuildKit-restrictions) but in general if an environment where emulation can't be run for security reasons, how can you build multi-arch dockerfiles that only need to copy files to make another layer based off an existing multi-arch image. This shouldn't need to actually run a container in order to build the image, right? How can a simple build like this be run that is guaranteed not to launch an emulated container?

Edit: Here is an example file. This uses dotnet, but that same idea should apply to any language where the app deployed is not platform specific. I think all of these docker directives should just modify metadata or directly write an image layer, not actually require running a container.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY app .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you post an example of such Dockerfile?

Comment: @funnydman Sure. I added an example at the end.

Comment: Have you tried running this with buildkit/buildx? What errors did you encounter?